# Mousenter on only individual div

Tags: jquery, find, mouseenter

I have 3 divs with the same class which means when I hover over one it activates all of them. I had a look and it said if you use $(this).find() it will fix that problem. However my code doesn't work when i do this and I wondered if anyone could tell me what I was doing wrong? And how to make it so that it only activates one div at a time.

```
<div class="indvWorkwrap col-lg-4">
    <div class="work">
        <div class="front"><img src="images/work1.png"></div>
        <div class="back"><img src="images/work1_hover.png"></div>
        <div class="details">
            <header>
                <h1>MAGAZINE STARTUP for THE SAUCE</h1>
                <p>Branding, web & magazine layout</p>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="work">
        <div class="front"><img src="images/work1.png"></div>
        <div class="back"><img src="images/work1_hover.png"></div>
        <div class="details">
            <header>
                <h1>MAGAZINE STARTUP for THE SAUCE</h1>
                <p>Branding, web & magazine layout</p>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="work">
        <div class="front"><img src="images/work1.png"></div>
        <div class="back"><img src="images/work1_hover.png"></div>
        <div class="details">
            <header>
                <h1>MAGAZINE STARTUP for THE SAUCE</h1>
                <p>Branding, web & magazine layout</p>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery Code :**

```
$('.front').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.details header').delay(100).animate({
        bottom: '-100px'
    });
    $(this).find('.back').delay(400).fadeIn(200);
});

$('.back').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).delay(100).fadeOut(200);
    $(this).find('.details header').delay(400).animate({
        bottom: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: can you share the html??

Comment: Show us the html please

Comment: providing a jsfiddle would be better!

Comment: Posting the Html is better than a jsfiddle.  Always post in the question in case jsfiddle is not available when someone else reads this in the future (both is better, in fairness).

Comment: Sorry i have posted the HTML. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `siblings()` and `next()` instead of find. As find searches in descendants and you need to search the siblings.

```
$('.front').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).siblings ('.details').find('header').delay(100).animate({
        bottom: '-100px'
    });
    $(this).next('.back').delay(400).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Comment: I think it should be `$(this).siblings('.details').find(' header')`